# Css Weird Spacing at the bottom of the page

Tags: css, image, layer

At the bottom of my index page, there is a large spacing at the bottom. Now I know what is causing this, which is the two characters on the sides of the page. I don't know why or how to fix it. Any help would be most appreciated.

Html Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Arakion - Homepage</title>
<html>
<link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<head>
<style type = "text/css">

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="Wrapper">
  <div id="navbar" style="display: inline-block;">
<ul id="nav">
    <li id="top">
        <a href="home:index.html">HOME</a>
    </li>

    <li id="top">
        <a href="#">GUIDE</a>
        <ul>
        <li id="submenu"><a href="Htdocs/guides/classes.php">CLASSES</a></li>
        <li id="submenu"><a href="Htdocs/guides/dungeons.php">DUNGEONS</a></li>
        <li id="submenu"><a href="Htdocs/guides/monsters.php">MONSTERS</a></li>
        <li id="submenu"><a href="Htdocs/guides/pets.php">PETS</a></li>
        <li id="submenu"><a href="Htdocs/guides/races.php">RACES</a></li>
        <li id="submenu"><a href="Htdocs/guides/town buildings.php">TOWN BUILDINGS</a></li>
        <li id="submenu"><a href="Htdocs/guides/universe.php">UNIVERSE</a></li>
        <li id="submenu"><a href="Htdocs/guides/wiki.php">WIKI</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="top">
        <a href="#">BLOG</a>

        <ul>
        <li id="submenu"><a href="Htdocs/blogs/arakion.php">ARAKION</a></li>
        <li id="submenu"><a href="Htdocs/blogs/chris taylor.php">CHRIS TAYLOR</a></li>
        </ul>

    </li>
    <li id="top">
        <a href="#">MEDIA</a>
        <ul>
        <li id="submenu"><a href="Htdocs/media/art.php">CONCEPT ART</a></li>
        <li id="submenu"><a href="Htdocs/media/screenshots.php">SCREENSHOTS</a></li>
        <li id="submenu"><a href="Htdocs/media/videos.php">VIDEOS</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="top">
        <a href="Php/forum/index.php">FORUM</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div style="display: inline-block;" id="sidebar_header"><img src="images/Progress/KickstarterGoalBar_0.png" width="310" height="80"/></div>
<div style="display: inline-block;" id="sidebar_banner">
  <div id="Sidebar_content">
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>Social Media</p>
    <p><img src="images/Side Banner_Line.png" width="100%" height="10" /></p>
    <p><a herf="#" target="_new"><img src="images/KickstarterIcon.png"/></a> <a href="http://www.indiedb.com/games/arakion" target="_new"><img src="images/IndieDBIcon.png" width="35" height="35" /></a> 
        <a href="http://www.facebook.com/Arakion" target="_new"><img src="images/FacebookIcon.png" width="35" height="35" /></a> <a href="http://twitter.com/arakiongame" target="_new"> 
            <img src="images/TwitterICon.png" width="35" height="35" /> </a> <a href="http://www.youtube.com/user/MrLavidimus" target="_new"> <img src="images/YoutubeICon.png" width="35" height="35" /> </a> </p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>Random Media</p>
    <p><img src="images/Side Banner_Line.png" width="100%" height="10" /></p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>Something</p>
    <p><img src="images/Side Banner_Line.png" width="100%" height="10" /></p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
  </div></div>
<div style="display: inline-block;" id="main_background">
  <div id="main_content"><div id="main_img"><img src="images/MainImages/Main_Placeholder_img.jpg"/></div>
    <table width="600" height="106" border="0" id="main_section_img" style="margin-left: 15px;">
      <tr>
        <td width="140"><img src="images/MainImages/Placeholder1.jpg"  height="100%" width="100%"/></td>
        <td width="140"><img src="images/MainImages/Placeholder2.jpg"  height="100%" width="100%"/></td>
        <td width="140"><img src="images/MainImages/Placeholder3.jpg"  height="100%" width="100%"/></td>
        <td width="140"><img src="images/MainImages/Placeholder4.jpg"  height="100%" width="100%"/></td>
      </tr>
  </table>
    <table width="561" border="0" style="text-align: center;">
      <tr>
        <td width="140">How Housing Works and why we have it</td>
        <td width="140">An In depth look at the Satyr race</td>
        <td width="140">We take a look at the role the alchemist plays in a group</td>
        <td width="140">Our doors are offically open to new employees apply today</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
  </div></div>
<div style="display: inline-block;" id="sub_background_1"><div id="sub_content">
  <div id="Sub_title">Kickstarter has just opened!</div><div id="Sub_subtitle">by Chris Taylor 7-24-2012</div><div id="Sub_image" style="display: inline-block;">
    <img src="images/MainImages/Sub_Placeholder.jpg"  height="100%" width="100%"/></div>
  <div id="Sub_text"> sUt enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborumLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt  ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, <a href="index.html">Read More.</a></div></div></div>
<div style="display: inline-block;" id="sub_background_2"><div id="sub_content">
  <div id="Sub_title">Kickstarter has just opened!</div><div id="Sub_subtitle">by Chris Taylor 7-24-2012</div><div id="Sub_image" style="display: inline-block;">
    <img src="images/MainImages/Sub_Placeholder.jpg"  height="100%" width="100%"/></div>
  <div id="Sub_text">  Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborumLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt  ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, <a href="index.html">Read More.</a></div></div></div>
<div style="display: inline-block;" id="sub_background_3"><div id="sub_content">
  <div id="Sub_title">Kickstarter has just opened!</div><div id="Sub_subtitle">by Chris Taylor 7-24-2012</div><div id="Sub_image" style="display: inline-block;">
    <img src="images/MainImages/Sub_Placeholder.jpg"  height="100%" width="100%"/></div>
  <div id="Sub_text"> sUt enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborumLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt  ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, <a href="index.html">Read More.</a></div></div></div>
<div style="display: inline-block;" id="sub_background_4"><div id="sub_content">
  <div id="Sub_title">Kickstarter has just opened!</div><div id="Sub_subtitle">by Chris Taylor 7-24-2012</div><div id="Sub_image" style="display: inline-block;">
    <img src="images/MainImages/Sub_Placeholder.jpg"  height="100%" width="100%"/></div>
  <div id="Sub_text">  Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborumLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt  ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, <a href="index.html">Read More.</a></div></div></div>
<div id="footer_background" style=" text-align: center; ">
    <img src="images/Footer_Divider.png" height="10px" width="600px"/>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
COPYRIGHT 2012 CHRIS TAYLOR ALL RIGHTS RESERVED | CODED BY SEAN HALL</a></div>
        <div id="left"><img src="images/Backgrounds/left.png" width="350px" height="900px" /></div>
        <div id="right"><img src="images/Backgrounds/Right.png" width="350px" height="900px" /></div>
</div>
```

Css Code:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'KingthingsExeterRegular';
    src: url('font/kingthings_exeter-webfont.eot');
    src: url('font/kingthings_exeter-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('font/kingthings_exeter-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('font/kingthings_exeter-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('font/kingthings_exeter-webfont.svg#KingthingsExeterRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
body {
    font-family: 'KingthingsExeterRegular';
    overflow-y: auto;
}
body,td,th {
    font-family: KingthingsExeterRegular;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 13px;
}
a:link {
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFF;
}
a:hover {
    color: #FFF;
}
a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
}
/*Body Css */
#header{
  z-index: -999;
  width:900px ;
  height:800px ;
  position: relative;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}
#left{
  z-index:-2;
  width:250px;
  height:600px ;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  top:-2050px;
  left:-210px;

}
#right{
  z-index:-2;
  width:250px;
  height:600px ;
  position: relative;
  float:right;
  clear: both;
  top:-2600px;
  left:100px;
}
#Wrapper {
    width:1040px;
    margin:auto;
    margin-top:200px;
    height:2000px;
}
/*------------------------------------*\
    NAV
\*------------------------------------*/
#navbar{
    position: relative;
    top:91px;
    float:left;
    margin-top:50px;
    margin-left:5px;
    width:649px;
    height: 50px;
    z-index:4;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    clear:both;
}
#nav{
    list-style:none;
    font-weight:bold;
    width:600;
    height:50;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}
#top{
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    background-image:url("images/Button_NavBar_Unselected.png");
    height:55px;
    width:119px;
    font-size:15px;
}
#top:hover{
    background-image:url("images/Button_NavBar_Hover.png")
}
#submenu{
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    height:20px;
    width:100px;
    font-size: 12px;
}
#nav a{
    display:block;
    padding-top:20px;
    z-index:-1;
    font-family:"Arial";
}
/*--- DROPDOWN ---*/
#nav ul{
    list-style:none;
    position:absolute;
    left:-9999px; 
}
#nav ul li{
    padding-top:1px; 
    float:none;
}
#nav ul a{
    white-space:nowrap;
}
#nav li:hover ul{ 
    left:-30px;
    top:40px;
}
#nav li:hover a{ /* These create persistent hover states, meaning the top-most link stays 'hovered' even when your cursor has moved down the list. */

}
#nav li:hover ul a{ /* The persistent hover state does however create a global style for links even before they're hovered. Here we undo these effects. */

}
#nav li:hover ul li a:hover{ /* Here we define the most explicit hover states--what happens when you hover each individual link. */

}
/* Main Block */
#main_background{
    width:680px;
    height:519px;
    float:left;
    background-image:url(images/MainSection.png);
}
#main_content{
    width:590px;
    height:430px;
    text-align:left;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-left:45px;
}
#main_img{
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-top:5px;
    background-image:url(images/MainSection_BigImageHighlight.png);
    width:520px;
    height:300px;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:4px;
}
#main_section_img{
    margin-top:10px;
    background-image:url(mages/MainSection_SmallImageInsett.png);
    width:560px;
    height:95px;
}
/* Sub Block */
/*  Sub Background Hierarchy */
#sub_background_1{
    position:relative;
    width:610px;
    height:270px;
    float:left;
    background-image: url(images/SubSection_Base.png);
    z-index:-1;
    margin-left:30px;
    top:-38px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
#sub_background_2{
    position:relative;
    width:610px;
    height:270px;
    float:left;
    background-image: url(images/SubSection_Base.png);
    z-index:-2;
    margin-left:30px;
    top:-52px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
#sub_background_3{
    position:relative;
    width:610px;
    height:270px;
    float:left;
    background-image: url(images/SubSection_Base.png);
    z-index:-3;
    margin-left:30px;
    top:-65px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
#sub_background_4{
    position:relative;
    width:610px;
    height:270px;
    float:left;
    background-image: url(images/SubSection_Base.png);
    z-index:-4;
    margin-left:30px;
    top:-77px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
#sub_background_5{
    position:relative;
    width:610px;
    height:270px;
    float:left;
    background-image: url(images/SubSection_Base.png);
    z-index:-5;
    margin-left:30px;
    top:-83px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
#sub_background_6{
    position:relative;
    width:610px;
    height:270px;
    float:left;
    background-image: url(images/SubSection_Base.png);
    z-index:-6;
    margin-left:30px;
    top:-81px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
#sub_background_7{
    position:relative;
    width:610px;
    height:270px;
    float:left;
    background-image: url(images/SubSection_Base.png);
    z-index:-7;
    margin-left:30px;
    top:-81px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
#sub_background_8{
    position:relative;
    width:610px;
    height:270px;
    float:left;
    background-image: url(images/SubSection_Base.png);
    z-index:-8;
    margin-left:30px;
    top:-85px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
/* Hierarchy End */
#sub_content{
    width:580px;
    height:220px;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-top:10px;
    clear: both;
}
#Sub_title{
    height:35px;
    width:400px;
    margin-top:30px;
    margin-left:10px;
    font-size:30px;
    text-align: left;
}
#Sub_subtitle{
    height:20px;
    width:200px;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-top:65;
    font-size:15px;
    text-align: left;
}
#Sub_image{
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-left:15px;
    float:left;
}
#Sub_text{
    height:180px;
    width:400px;
    float:right;
    margin-top:10px;
    text-align: left;
}
/* SideBar Block */
#sidebar_header{
    position:relative;
    height:80px;
    width:350px;
    float:right;
    background-image:url(images/Kickstarter.png);
    margin-right:5px;
    left:-20px;
    margin-top:10px;
    z-index:1;
    clear: both;
}
#sidebar_header img {
    margin-top:61px;
    height:18px;
    width:310;

}
#sidebar_banner{
    position:relative;
    height:729px;
    width:360px;
    float:right;
    background-image: url(images/Side%20Banner.png);
    left:-20px;
    z-index:-1;
    clear: both;
}
#Sidebar_content{
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-top:20px;
    text-align:center;
    font-size: 20px;
    width:300px;
    height:700px;
    line-height: 3px;
}

/* Footer */
#footer_background{
    position:relative;
    background-image:url(images/Footer.png);
    width:605px;
    height:75px;
    float:left;
    margin-left:35px;
    top:-89px;
    z-index:-9;
    line-height:1px;
    font-family:"Arial";
    font-size:10px;
}
#footer_background a:link{
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
#footer_background img {
    margin-top:100px;
}
```

Here is a live version of the site, scroll down to the bottom of the page and you will see the empty spacing. https://dl.dropbox.com/u/49665279/Arakion/index.html

Thank you.

Comment: Could be the Byte Order Mark of your document. Save it as UTF-8 **without** BOM and check if it works out.

Comment: The way you are building your HTML, is all wrong. It would be hard to fix it that way. Try fixing it by starting to build your website in 2 columns (a `div` for each column) which both are in inside your wrapper. You are still thinking about it as if it was a table layout (i.e. you are building your website in rows). For example, another problem in your website now, is that it is impossible to click the read more buttons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using an `</html>` at the end of your document might help :)

And for the css:

Change the `position` of the `#wrapper` to `relative`.

And then change the `position` of `#left` and `#right` to `absolute` .

And their `top` to something around `-175px`

Comment: I can't change it to absolute, otherwise it does not move with the wrapper.

Comment: It will once you make `#wapper{ position:relative; }`. Absolute positioned objects search for the first parent that has `position:absolute` or `position:relative`.

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the images on the side. You positioned them `relative` with `top:-2050px;`. This means these images are displayed 2000pixels furter on the top, but still take the space at the bottom of the page.

Try changing their position from `relative` to `fixed`. You might have to change the values of `top` and `left` as well.

EDIT: If you haven't used it, try firebug with firefox or the google chrom developer tools. They are pretty helpful in finding the source of problems like these. Also you can change or disable css options in one click, to find out which option it might be.

Comment: If I change it to Fixed, then it will move with the scroll.

Comment: @SeanHall My bad, try `absolute` instead, as Sem suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Use `margin-top/bottom: -(value)px;` instead of `position: (relative/absolute)` and you'll have no spaces left out.